# How could I run this as one command in Mongo Shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, arguments, updatemodel

```
db.people.update(
    { "age": "Thirty Two" }, { age: 32 }, { upsert: false }
)

db.people.update(
    { "age": "Fifty-Five" }, { age: 55 }, { upsert: false }
)

db.people.update(
    { "age": "Twenty" }, { age: 20 }, { upsert: false }
)
```

I was thinking:

```
db.people.update(
    [{ "age": "Thirty Two" }, { age: 32 }, { upsert: false }],
    [{ "age": "Fifty-Five" }, { age: 55 }, { upsert: false }],
    [{ "age": "Twenty" }, { age: 20 }, { upsert: false }]
)
```

But that didn't work.. I know im just really tired and can't think of it...

Comment: Do you want to use [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) or [`multi=true`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter)? The updates you have will replace at most one matching doc and replace it entirely with the update document. I'm guessing there's more to a person than just `{ "age" : 32 }` and there is more than one person aged 32.

Comment: Hi wd! I don't know about that, I'm new to mongo. Any possibility you could explain to me more. I was more just tryin to figure out how to do them all at once. What are my other options with $set and multi=true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment and present an alternative to `db.eval()`, a "operatorless" update replaces the entire matched document with the update document (except keeping the `_id`):

```
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "Barney Big", "age" : 32 }
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Sam Small", "age" : 26 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Mindy Medium", "age" : 26 }
> db.people.update({ "age" : 32 }, { "age" : 45 })
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : 0, "age" : 45 }
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Sam Small", "age" : 26 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Mindy Medium", "age" : 26 }
```

Changing only one field means using an [update operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1) like `$set`:

```
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "Barney Big", "age" : 32 }
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Sam Small", "age" : 26 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Mindy Medium", "age" : 26 }
> db.people.update({ "age" : 32 }, { "$set" : { "age" : 45 } })
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "Barney Big", "age" : 45 }
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Sam Small", "age" : 26 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Mindy Medium", "age" : 26 }
```

By default, updates affect only one matching document. The option `multi=true` will cause the update to affect all matching documents:

```
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "Barney Big", "age" : 32 }
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Larry Large", "age" : 32 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Sam Small", "age" : 26 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Mindy Medium", "age" : 26 }
> db.people.update({ "age" : 32 }, { "$set" : { "age" : 45 } })
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "Barney Big", "age" : 45 }
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Larry Large", "age" : 32 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Sam Small", "age" : 26 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Mindy Medium", "age" : 26 }
> db.people.update({ "age" : 26 }, { "$set" : { "age" : 23 } }, { "multi" : true })
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "Barney Big", "age" : 45 }
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Larry Large", "age" : 32 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Sam Small", "age" : 23 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Mindy Medium", "age" : 23 }
```

So, to do the updates you asked about in your question in the shell, I'd use a for loop but dispense with the `db.eval` in favor of multiple calls to `db.people.update()`

```
> updates = [
    [{ "age": "Thirty Two" }, { "$set" : { "age" : 32 } }],
    [{ "age": "Fifty-Five" }, { "$set" : { "age" : 55 } }],
    [{ "age": "Twenty" }, { "$set" : { "age" : 20 } }]
]
> updates.forEach(function(pair) {
    db.people.update(pair[0], pair[1])
})
```

If you have hundreds of updates and are using MongoDB 2.6 or later, look into [bulk operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/). There's more information in the [`db.collection.update()` docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter).

Comment: sorry it took me so long, just getting back to this project. I appreciate the answer I have marked yours as most helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want.

```
db.eval(function(name, options) {
    var coll = db.getCollection(name);
    for (var x in options) {
        var option = options[x];
        coll.update(option[0], option[1], option[2]);
    }
},
"people",
[
    [{ "age": "Thirty Two" }, { age: 32 }, { upsert: false }],
    [{ "age": "Fifty-Five" }, { age: 55 }, { upsert: false }],
    [{ "age": "Twenty" }, { age: 20 }, { upsert: false }]
]);
```

Comment: Dang I was one set of array brackets away huh. Ooh I like the eval function and loop thanks!

Comment: Please don't use `db.eval()`. Server-side javascript has lots of problems, including slowness, security vulnerability, and incompatibility with sharded collections. See more [in the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/).

Comment: @wdberkeley: I see the limitation of `db.eval()`. But sometimes it's probably the only way to solve specific issue before V2.6. For example, there are several thousands of documents to be modified at a batch. If updating one by one, maybe one minute is needed. About 2 seconds is enough when using `db.eval()`. Thanks anyway.